# strcmp giving wrong outputs

Tags: c, strcmp

So I studied that strcmp returns the difference between the asci value of the two characters being compared. But in my case it is giving a value of -1,0 or 1 only.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<strings.h>
int main()
{
    char n1[]="Jerry";
    char n2[]="Ferry";
    printf("%d",strcmp(n2,n1));
    return 0;
}
```

Ideally it should give -4,but dev cpp is giving an output of -1. Why is that?

Comment: That's fine — all that's required is a positive, negative or zero value; the magnitude is unspecified.  Your expectations are wrong.  See C11 standard on [`strcmp()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.4.2).

Comment: strcmp doesn't do that, you were misled.

Comment: You claim: _"strcmp returns the difference between the asci value of the two characters being compared."_. Where did you get this claim from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this the only return value for strcmp() in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015155/is-this-the-only-return-value-for-strcmp-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

strcmp gives the relative difference between 2 strings.

negative if the left item is less than right

0 if the left is the same as the right

positive if the left item is greater than the right

It doesn't give a range on the difference.

(HINT: what value for `strcmp( "Hello", "Hfllo")` ? )

Comment: Your summarise the spec helpfully though your phrasing "the relative difference" is likely to worsen OPs misunderstanding. Referring/linking to the spec it is probably appropriate. Also you might find ways of formatting your post more readable and suggestive here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: The hint might be less enlightening than you think, because coming up with a formula to determine the answer to the rhetoric question is not so hard and then the reaction is "So what?".