# strcmp returning 10 even the strings are the same

Tags: c, string, strcmp

for some reason when I compare two exact strings, it returns a number other than zero. I am not sure why is it doing this.

Shown here:

```
printf("%s %s %d\n",target,temp->variableName,strcmp(temp->variableName, target));
```

Result:"B B 10" <- when I compare B with B it returns 10 even though it should return 0.

Could someone tell me how come it is doing this and what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Show [mcve], please.

Comment: Some implementations just return the difference between the first 2 characters found that to not match. If you get 10 it seems that one of the buffers contains a `LF` (`0x0A`)

Comment: My crystal ball says please see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221).

Comment: I suggest changing the format string to `"[%s] [%s] [%d]\n"`

Comment: There are two options here. Either your `strcmp` has a bug (VERY unlikely) or you have a problem in code you have not shown. So please [edit] your question and provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `strcmp` is the ASCII value of the first delta (this is dependent on implementation, but most decent implementations will behave in this way).

ASCII of `10` is equal to `newline`. You most likely have a carriage return in one of the strings.

Comment: How is this downvoted?

Comment: Maybe you should not write that first sentence in that way. It can be done like this but the standard doesn't specify this.

Comment: Hm... while the first sentence is correct for any sane implementations, there is no guarantee that `strcmp` returns any ascii value of anything. _Any_ positive, zero or _any_ negative value is required. It's common to be confused when `strcmp` is inlined by the compiler and returns -1 instead of the difference, ex. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454144/why-the-returns-of-strcmp-is-different) and many other SO questions. You shouldn't depend on that.

Comment: @Woodstock I guess another reason for DV is that you're guessing before OP has corrected the question with a mre. And KamilCuk is correct. You should fix your answer. Nothing wrong with mentioning that many implementations solves it this way, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: if there was a new line the out put would have printed a new line, but output does not show new line, one of the `B` would have printed in next line

Comment: Not the downvoter - but fwiw, editing the first sentence to acknowledge the problem is _likely because the implementation of `strcmp` used_ ... (add your own words)

Comment: Not the downvoter

Comment: @IrAM Very  good point there

Comment: @ryyker Except that it isn't very likely according ti IrAM's analysis. And since OP does not want to fix the question with a [mre] I have close voted the question.

Comment: done thanks for thoughts

Comment: @klutt - I do not dispute your inclination, however I know that sometimes I am called away from my desk in the middle of a conversation in this forum at the most in-opportune times.  It may be that this person will come back and fix.

Comment: @ryyker Could be the case. Then you're just unlucky. :)

Comment: Thanks for re-enforcing my assumption about being busy for awhile :)

Comment: @klutt - on the contrary - In this current world condition, I consider myself very fortunate that I have work at all, and that it sometimes does require my attention :)

Comment: @ryyker Haha, true. And getting your question closed because of a phone call is not exactly the end of the world. :D